# Using interfaces in dependency injection in .Net MAUI

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, .net-maui

I am trying to implement dependency injection for the first time in my new project in .Net MAUI. For testing purposes, I want to fetch data from a local source in my ViewModel. The production scenario will fetch data from the remote data source using HttpClient.

Below is my code base structure:

**I have an Interface:**

```
 public interface IApiService
{
    Task<bool> GetSomething(string parameter);
    Task<string> GetSomethingElse(string parameter);
}
```

**I have two classes that derive from it.**

```
public class LocalDataStore: IApiService
public class RemoteDataStore: IApiService
```

**In my MauiProgram.cs, when I want to use Local Data Store:**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LocalDataStore>()

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApiService>()
```

**And for Remote Data Store**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RemoteDataStore>()

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApiService>()
```

In my ViewModel:

```
public class Page1ViewModel
{ 
   public Page1ViewModel(IApiService localDataStore)
      {
          var items = Task.Run(async () => await localDataStore.GetSomething(true));
      }
}
```

While running the app, I get an error :

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type '...IApiService' while attempting to activate 'ViewModels.Page1ViewModel'.'

What am I doing wrong or what else should I be doing?

Kindly help.

Thanks, and regards.

**Edit***

Of course, it works if I use LocalDataStore or RemoteDataStore instead of IApiService, when I register the services with the builder. But then if I have to change from one data store to another, I will have to change that in all the ViewModel classes?

Answer (score 3):

It was trivial.

I needed to register the service like so :

builder.Services.AddSingleton<**IApiService,LocalDataStore>**();

Thanks to https://youtu.be/paZNvvUNFi0, I realised that.

Hope this helps someone.